# Why do my hyperlinks in Excel change to a roaming folder?

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

I have created some hyperlinks in a workbook,

Using CTRL + K.

They worked as intended and opened the new workbooks when clicked.

A few hours later, the links have changed and they now link to a roaming folder ?

Orginal link was:

```
\\uk.finning.com\data\Group\Heavy Construction\New Sales\EF2C Dashboard\Demand & Supply\Surplus Stock.xlsm
```

New link is:

```
C:\Users\8997\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\Demand & Supply\Surplus Stock.xlsm
```

What is the cause of this ? and will other users clicking the link be able to get to the original document ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very simple to fix this "Hyper-Loss" problem. Either turn off "Autosave" or go to Options/Save and direct the autosave to default to the location that the files reside in.  For some reason, your file is auto saved every 10 minutes to a folder on your hard drive named user/appdata/roaming/Microsoft/Excel by default and if that your file is accidentally closed and the autosaved version pops up; it will have the new hyperlink location as you hover.  Turn off auto save and just hit save every now and then: Easier headache than replacing 50 hyperlinks like I had to do.

Comment: I don't see how this relates to the question being asked. OP is not asking about the link to the file they're working on, they're talking about _links inside cells_, AKA content. Why would the local autosave filepath affect the content of cells in a worksheet at all?

Answer (score 2):

Excel should never ever update a hyperlink on its own, no matter if the link works, is broken, if you saving location works or is broken.

**I propose the following fix:**

1. In Excel open the File menu and select options
2. In the Options select 'Advanced'. Scroll down to the general section
3. Select the button 'Web Options'
4. In the Web Options dialog select the tab 'Files'
5. Unselect 'Update links on save'

In my opinion, disabling 'Update links on save' should be the default setting, because this option makes more troubles than it helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is the best answer for this problem. A terrible buggy behaviour of Excel! Certainly that should be [ ] Update links on save (disabled) by default, or that functionality shouldn't exist in the first place. But changing that options fixes the problem (you have to re-enter the broken links, but then it seemed to stay unmodified).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to stop Excel from doing this unless you do not save over the original.

From [*Description of link management and storage in Excel*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328440):

> There are several circumstances in which links between files can be inadvertently made to point to erroneous locations. The following are two of the most common scenarios.
>
> Scenario 1:
>
> 1. You map a drive under the root of a share. For example, you map drive Z to \Server\Share\Folder1.
> 2. You create links to a workbook that is stored at the mapped location after you open the file through that mapped drive.
> 3. You open the file by a UNC path.
>
> As a consequence the link will be broken.
>
> If you close the file without saving it, the links will not be changed. However, if you save the file before you close it, you will save the links with the current broken path. The folders between the root of the share and the mapped folder will be left out of the path. In the example above, the link would change to \Server\Folder1. In other words, the Share name is eliminated from the path.
>
> Scenario 2:
>
> 1. You map a drive under the root of a share. For example, you map drive Z to \Server\Share\Folder1.
> 2. You open the file by a UNC path or a mapped drive mapped to a different folder on the share, such as \Server\Share\Folder2.
> 3. As a consequence, the link will be broken.
>
> If you close the file without saving it, the links will not be changed. However, if you save the file before you close it, you will save the links with the current broken path. The folders between the root of the share and the mapped folder will be left out of the path. In the example above, the link would change to \Server\Folder1.

Comment: Welcome to Super User and thank you for your answer. Is there anything you can quote from the KB article in your answer (by [editing it in][(https://superuser.com/posts/1317475/edit)) ?

Answer (score 0):

Open the excel file with hyperlinks > File > Save as > choose the extension "Excel Binary" > More options > Locate the folder where you want to paste it without damaging links. Done.